# Using Tidhttp with Twebbrowser

Tags: delphi, internet-explorer, activex, indy, twebbrowser

I am using the tidhttp control to speed up the loading of a webpage in a Twebbrowser. Navigating to the url is slow so thats why I don't use it(`WebBrowser1.Navigate('some_url_here')`). Here is how i do it:

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
  procedure LoadHtmlIntoBrowser(var WB: TweBbrowser; const HTMLString: string);
  var
    v: OleVariant;
    HTMLDocument: IHTMLDocument2;
  begin
    WB.Navigate('about:blank');
    while WB.ReadyState < READYSTATE_INTERACTIVE do
      forms.Application.ProcessMessages;

    if Assigned(WB.Document) then
    begin
      HTMLDocument := WB.Document as IHTMLDocument2;
      v := VarArrayCreate([0, 0], varVariant);
      v[0] := HTMLString;
      HTMLDocument.Write(PSafeArray(TVarData(v).VArray));
      HTMLDocument.Close;
    end;
    forms.Application.ProcessMessages;
  end;

var
  str:string;
begin
  str:=idhttp1.Get('http://localhost/myhome.html');
  LoadHtmlIntoBrowser(WebBrowser1,str);
end;
```

I use the `idHTTP` to get the html content into a string then write that string directly to Webbrowser. I have a local webserver setup(XAMPP). The problem I having is that after the html content has been written to the browser and I click a link that is displayed, it goes no where i.e. it shows a mostly blank page with "twopage.html" at the top. When I right click and "view source" i get `"<html>twopage.html</html>"` which is strange and not the actual html of the page.

The "myhome.html" file contains

```html
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body><h1>My home</h1><a href="twopage.html"></a></body>
</html>
```

`The other webpage, "twopage.html" contains`

```html
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body><h1>Another Webpage</h1></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your web browser have no "base url" to properly construct the relative links the way it normally does when you really navigate to `http://somewhere`. I don't know if you can _inform_ it what that "base url" is, but you for sure can change your "myhome.html" file to include absolute links, for example `<a href="http://localhost/twopage.html">`, which I bet will work in your setup. On the other hand, I really don't see how this can improve the time to load the page in a significant way, and I'm not sure if it works with a complex page involving related resources, like css, images and the such

Comment: I agree with @jachguate, [`maybe it's not even possible`](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/b98fd2b3-72d5-4aab-83d3-40feb01bacef) without at least one real navigation to the desired location.

Comment: I am changing the links to absolute. This does not solve the problem but only works around it. This will do for now. Thanks.

Comment: @Jachguate, I expect that this specific code and the local server are just for testing. With a remote server, this could be useful for "pre-loading" some pages. However, if that's the intention, then we wouldn't really care whether TWebBrowser can directly navigate to the other links since we'd want to fetch them from the pre-load cache instead. If it's not just for testing, then using absolute links isn't much of a workaround since the *whole thing* feels like a workaround for some *other* problem.

Comment: @jachguate: You can insert a `<base>` tag into the HTML before loading it into the `webbrowser`, so that the webbrowser has a base url to resolve relative links with.

Comment: @Rob that's why I posted it as a comment not as an answer, just providing some insight on the cause, but not the solution to the _problem_.

Comment: @Remy you shall post that as an answer!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to insert a `<base>` tag into the HTML before loading it into the web browser, so that it has a base url available when resolving relative urls.

Comment: this works great. Remy, I also want to discuss an issue you "off the air".